# Error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, double

I am working on a project and I keep getting error messages saying error: incompatible types int[] cannot be converted to int, when trying to compile. The error says it is on line 17. I have tried changing everything to doubles and I get the same error for doubles. I do not know why the numbers are unable to store and an explanation would be very helpful.

```
    int[][] houseNumbers;
    int numberOfHouses, homeNumber, numberOfPeople, house, people;
    System.out.print("How many houses in the street?: ");
    numberOfHouses = keyboard.nextInt();
    houseNumbers = new int[numberOfHouses][];
    for (house = 0; house < houseNumbers.length; house++){
        System.out.print("What is the next house number? : ");
        houseNumbers[house] = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How many people live in house number" + houseNumbers[house] + ":");
        numberOfPeople = keyboard.nextInt();
        houseNumbers[house] = new int[numberOfPeople];
        for (people = 0; people < houseNumbers[house].length; people++){
            System.out.print("What is the age of person " + people + ": ");
            houseNumbers[house][people] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `houseNumbers[house] = keyboard.nextInt();` Assigning an `int` to an `int` array. Three lines later you do it correctly. You probably want `numberOfPeople = keyboard.nextInt();` there.

Comment: So I did : homeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
houseNumbers[house] = homeNumber;     and I am still getting the same error

Comment: And what is wrong with assigning an int to an int array?

Comment: What's wrong is that Java doesn't allow you to do it.  Period.  An `int` is not an `int` array.  Now some languages will say "Oh ... perhaps she means me to turn the `int` into an `int[]` with one element" ... and do it for you.  Java isn't like that.  Java insists that you say what you mean.

Comment: `houseNumbers[house]` is an array. You can't assign an `int` to it.  You have to allocate space for the array, then you can assign to each element: `houseNumbers[house] = new int[numberOfPeople];`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, I thought I was storing values but I really should've been creating a certain sized array and then storing the values. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors. The biggest one is trying to assign an `int` to an `int` array. An array is a block of (one or more) items. You have to allocate the block with `new` before you can access the individual items. Your compiler is telling you this. Learn to understand the compiler's errors and warnings.

Error 1:

```
/* houseNumbers[house] -> */ homeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Error 2:

```
System.out.print("How many people live in house number" + /* houseNumbers[house] -> */ homeNumber + ":");
```